# Bind the child component form to parent component form

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular7

I have two components **parent** and **child**.
I have created the two form group for parent and child in there respective components

> in reactive form model

and I have to bind the child form group to the parent form group.
Is it possible to do.

Note:
*I am passing the parent form to child component*

Comment: By binding, do you mean passing the data upstream to the parent? Or are you referring to the entire form state?

Comment: You can do this using input and output

Comment: Share the code & effort which you have put into.

Comment: I have done this passing the parent form to the child.I have created the new form group for the child form in **child.component.ts** and _created the observerable for the child form while the child form value changes i will update the validity for the parent form_  Is this approach is correct?

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to create to form group for this.
You have to pass parent form group to the child.

Create formgroup and formcontrol in parent component and pass fromcontrol and formgroup in child component using @input.

Whenever you will submit form you will get values from child component fields too.

Go through the below code
 **Parent Component**

```
<form [formGroup]="operatorForm" #formElement>
    <div class="inner">
      <!-- <h6>Donation Collected</h6> Text only For Churches Panel -->
      <app-date-filter
        [fromDate]="fromDate"
        [toDate]="toDate"
        [dateForm]="operatorForm"
      ></app-date-filter>
      <div>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select
            formControlName="status"
            (selectionChange)="filterChange($event)"
            placeholder="Filter Type"
          >
            <mat-option [value]="FILTER_TYPE.active"> Active </mat-option>
            <mat-option [value]="FILTER_TYPE.blocked"> Blocked </mat-option>
            <mat-option [value]="FILTER_TYPE.deleted"> Deleted </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>


    </div>
    <div class="btn-wrap filterBtns">
      <button
        mat-raised-button
        (click)="reset()"
        [disabled]="!operatorForm.dirty"
      >
        Reset
      </button>
      <button
        (click)="filter()"
        mat-raised-button
        color="primary"
        class="ml10 mat-filter-button"
        [disabled]="!operatorForm.dirty"
      >
        Filter
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
this.operatorForm = this._fb.group({
  fromDate: ['', []],
  toDate: ['', []],
  status: [null, []]
});
get fromDate():FormControl{ 
 return this.operatorForm.controls['fromDate'] as FormControl 
} 
get toDate():FormControl{
 return this.operatorForm.controls['toDate'] as FormControl
}
```

**Child Component**

```
    @Input() fromDate: FormControl;
  @Input() toDate: FormControl;

  @Input() dateForm: FormGroup;

    <div class="inner" [formGroup]="dateForm">
  <label for="">Added On</label>
  <div class="column">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input
        matInput
        readonly
        [matDatepicker]="frompicker"
        formControlName="fromDate"
        placeholder="From"
      />
      <mat-datepicker-toggle
        matSuffix
        [for]="frompicker"
      ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #frompicker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input
        matInput
        readonly
        [matDatepicker]="topicker"
        formControlName="toDate"
        placeholder="To"
      />
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="topicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #topicker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: About your code: 1.-fromDate and ToDate are strings, not formControl and you should use `[fromDate]="'fromDate'"` and `[toDate]="'toDate'"`. Another aproach is pass really a FormControl like your forked code in https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-checkbox-al9yzn?file=app%2Fchild.html

Comment: As I said that Create formgroup and formcontrol in parent component and pass formcontrol and formgroup in child component using @input. 
So fromDate and toDate will be formcontrol not string.

get fromDate():FormControl{
  return this.formGroup.controls['fromDate'] as FormControl
}

get toDate():FormControl{
  return this.formGroup.controls['toDate'] as FormControl
}

Comment: Sorry, I dont' see this detail. Anyway, the reason your code work if because you pass dateForm, you not use fromDate or toDate in the child

Comment: fromDate and toDate are formcontrol passed by using @input and they are used in child component to get the values of both fields and they are bind to formGroup. By this way we can access child formcontrol in parent component.

Comment: @Brijseh, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-checkbox-zmeqc3?file=app/child.ts. It's your code removing `@Input() fromDate`and `@Input() toDate`. The "reason" is that you pass the formGroup. The formGroup is like another object. You pass the "memory adress", so you can change the value of the properties of the object in child

Comment: Thanks for the replay @brijesh
What my doubt is i have to create the Formgroup for the child component in  'child.component.ts' and the child form group should be binded to parent form while the child component loaded

Note:I will pass the parent form to child form

Comment: I have done this passing the parent form to the child.I have created the new form group for the child form in **child.component.ts** and _created the observerable for the child form while the child form value changes i will update the validity for the parent form_  Is this approach is correct? @Brijesh